# Add direct 10GB connection on separate network

Tags: networking, windows-10, 10gbit

I am trying to setup a direct 10GB connection between my Windows 10 PC and my Diskstation D1817+ for fast photo / video editing.  I have installed the 10GB cards in both and have connected via a CAT 7 cable.

Both the PC and the Diskstation are already connected to my gigabit LAN via a switch which will stay in place.

How do I configure the IP addresses etc of the 10GB cards so that they communicate directly with each other?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use what ever IP addressing scheme you like as long as you follow these three rules:

1. The IP addresses on both 10GB network cards must be on the same subnet.
2. The subnet they are on should be different to the subnet of your LAN (you can use IP addresses from your main LAN, but this would complicate matters and you'd have to start getting into programming static routes).
3. Use a private IP subnet so you don't conflict with a real IP address on the Internet you might one day want to access.

So for example, if your regular LAN is on the `192.168.0.0/16` subnet, you could use `10.0.0.0/8` for your 10GB cards. Give the PC the IP address `10.0.0.1` and the Diskstation `10.0.0.2`. Set the default gateway for the 10B connection on each device to be the other device (i.e. program the default gateway on the PC as `10.0.0.2`).

Comment: Not the default gateway, I hope. You mean the gateways on the 10 Gb/s adapters. If possible they should be left blank. If a value is required the ip of the other end is best. The normal default gateway on both devices should remain set to the default gateway of the normal LAN.

Comment: @Tonny, I mean the default gateway for that connection, which it's how it's labelled as such in Windows (7 at least) network adapter settings. I understand this is a slightly ambiguous term but this is how it is.

Comment: I get what you mean :-) MS obviously designed this with the idea that a computer mostly would only have 1 interface, which automatically makes it the default gateway. I wish Microsoft stopped mislabeling things/redefining terms just to make it "easier" for dumb users. In the end it isn't helping anyone. It just causes confusion, when you need to deal with the somewhat more complicated cases.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite easy, if you only want a point 2 point connection between the 2.
Pick for each 10 Gb/s adapter an ip-address 192.168.x.y
x should be a different number (in the range 0-255) than is used by you normal LAN. E.g If your normal LAN used 192.168.1.??? for teh devices you could pick 192.168.2.??? for the 10 Gb/s adapters.
y should be different numbers on each adapter from the range 1 to 254.
Set the netmask on each adapter to 255.255.255.0 and that is all there is to it.

Please note: This works best if (on the PC) you use the Syno ip-address directly to talk to it. If you do it by name there is still a chance the connection will go via the normal LAN. (This can also be prevented by putting the name and 10 Gb/s ip-address of the Syno in the "hosts" file on the PC.)

Comment: This worked to get the connection working, but the PC continues to default to the LAN connection, even though I have added the synology 10GB IP and name to the host file.  I verified this by disabling the LAN connection which results in double the file transfer speeds.  Is there anything else I should check / do to ensure the 10GB connection is the default?

Comment: @morgo1968 Mmhhh... There is very little control you can exert over WIndows when it decides it knows better than your do. You could try to use the Windows firewall to forbid all traffic to the Syno via the normal LAN interface. After a reboot of the PC it shoudl realize there is only one path to the Syno. Not sure how well that would work. Never tried that particular combination myself.

Comment: Think I have sorted this now.  I changed the Service Order for the connections in the Diskstation interface, placing the 10GB connection above the LAN connection and instantly file transfer speed doubled again.

Comment: @morgo1968 Good job! You may want to think about writing your own self-answer (that is allowed on this site) and explain the full details. It might help other people in the future with similar issues. Just leaving it in the comments isn't a good idea, as comments can be deleted.